# PHP imagettftext height is wrong with accent

Tags: php, gd, diacritics

I'm creating a font converter (ttf to C array) using PHP and *imagettftext*. It works well but when I convert letters with accent (e.g. Á) the accent is out of the area. In the example I convert some letters with Arial font with 20 px height. (letter, y top coordinate, y bottom coordinate).

- A: 0 15
- Á: -4 15
- y: 4 20
- Y: 0 15
- h: 0 15
- _: 17 20

Generated by this code:

```
   $co = imagettftext($im, $h_pt, 0, 0, $h_pt, $white, $font, $letter);
   echo($letter . ": " .$co[7] . "  " . $co[1]. "<br>");
```

The top coordinate of 'Á' is -4 so it not fits to the 0 .. 20 range. How is it possible? I thought the font should fit into its height.

So my question is how to "force" *imagettftext* to put accents into the given height?

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?  Bug [#53504](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53504) was fixed in PHP [7.0.12](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.12) and fixed many (all?) of the problems with `imagettfbbox`.

Comment: @timclutton I tried with PHP 7.0.24 but same result.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, I've found [this article](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align) about how font metrics work.

It turned out that the 20px height doesn't mean the font will fit a 20px heigh line. There are several (sometimes confusing) metrics to determine the height of the ascent and descent parts. This Wikipedia article gives a [quick overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)).